# SVN repository has spaces in the directory names

Tags: subgit

I am trying to use subgit to create a link between an existing SVN repo and a new git repo.

The directory names in the SVN repo have spaces in them which I think is creating a problem when I try to create a configuration.

Is there a way around it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of SubGit developers and as I know there's no problem when directories names contain spaces.

If you have spaces in branch names, use spaces in the config file:

```
branches = branches/branch with space:refs/heads/branch with space
excludeBranches = branches/branch to exclude
```

Well, if the space is the last character, you have to put the value in quotes because Git config format requires that:

```
branches = "branches/space at the end :refs/heads/spaces at the end "
```

I would also note that Git does not allow spaces in the branches name and physically in the Git repository it will be encoded to '+':

```
refs/heads/spaces+at+the+end+
```

but in the config you specify its version with spaces.
Also you can use just spaces in excludePath/includePath options:

```
includePath = /directory with space
excludePath = /directory with space/subdirectory with space
```

If you have other problems or questions, leave a command, I'll update the answer then.